# When does the Laplace Transform converge?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Consider the following function in the $s$-domain:

$$F(s) = \frac{1}{(s^2 + 1)(2s-1)}$$

My book concludes that the ROC (Region of convergence) must be $\Re(s) > 1/2$ because

a) The ROC can't contain poles

b)The ROC must be a right half plane.

The first point makes sense, but I don't get the second point. Could someone explain why it's necessary? Why isn't the ROC all $s$ such that $s \neq 1/2, j, -j$?

Comment: What is "ROC" here?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Region of Convergence.

Comment: Convergence of what? You are just writing a function.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The region that the Laplace transform exists (in other word the values of $s$ for which the Laplace integral is a finite value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Laplace Transform of a function $f$ is
$$
F(s)=\int_0^\infty\,f(t)e^{-st}\,dt.
$$
The imaginary part of $s$ bears no influence in whether the integral converges. And one can show that if the integral does not converge for a certain $s$, then it doesn't converge for all $s$ with smaller real part. In other words, the ROC is always of the form $\text{Re}(s)\geq c$ or $\text{Re}(s)>c$ for a given real number $c$.

In some detail, suppose that the integral converges for $s_0=c+ib$. Then, if $s=a+id$ with $a>c$, we have, integrating by parts,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt&=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-s_0t}\,e^{-(s-s_0)t}\,dt\\ \ \\
&=e^{-(s-s_0)t}\,\left.\left(\int_0^tf(v)e^{-s_0v}\,dv\right)\right|_0^\infty
+(s-s_0)\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-s_0)t}\left(\int_0^tf(v)e^{-s_0v}\,dv\right)\,dt\\ \ \\
&=(s-s_0)\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-s_0)t}\left(\int_0^tf(v)e^{-s_0v}\,dv\right)\,dt\\ \ \\
&=(s-s_0)\int_0^\infty e^{-(a-c)t}e^{-(d-b)t\,i}\left(\int_0^tf(v)e^{-s_0v}\,dv\right)\,dt.
\end{align}
This last integral converges absolutely because the integral between brackets is bounded by the existence of $F(s_0)$ (dependent on $f$ being nice enough) and then the exponential with negative exponent coefficient $-(a-c)$ forces convergence. The imaginary part $e^{-(d-b)t\,i}$ does not influence the absolute convergence because $|e^{-(d-b)t\,i}|=1$ for all $d,b,t$.

Comment: `The imaginary part of ss bears no influence in whether the integral converges.` Could you explain why please?

Comment: `And one can show that if the integral does not converge for a certain ss, the it doesn't converge for all ss with smaller real part. ` Could you show this please? I wasn't able to find a proof online.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: A minor point: I assume you meant the imaginary part of $s$ bears no influence on the _absolute_ convergence (consider e.g. $f(t) = \frac{1}{1+t}$)?

Comment: The phrase should be interpreted in terms of what is done after it. Even in your example, the imaginary part does not influence convergence if the real part of $s $ is positive. One usually wants to see $L [f] $ as a holomorphic functions, so you want an open domain; for your  $f $, the domain is Re $(s)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform of a function has the following bound: take $s=\sigma+it$, $\sigma, t$ real
$$ \lvert \mathcal{L}(f)(\sigma+it) \rvert = \left\lvert \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\sigma x-itx} f(x) \, dx \right\rvert \\
 \leqslant \int_0^{\infty} \lvert e^{-\sigma x}e^{-itx} \rvert \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx \\
 = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\sigma x} \lvert f(x) \rvert \, dx = \mathcal{L}(\lvert f \lvert )(\sigma) $$
Therefore if the Laplace transform of $\lvert f \rvert$ converges at $s=\sigma_0$, the Laplace transform of $f$ converges for all $s$ with real part $\sigma_0$. (And hence the region of convergence contains the half-plane $\sigma \geqslant \sigma_0$)

As for why the Laplace transform doesn't converge everywhere: if $f$ grows as fast as $e^{kx}$, then the integrand will not decay as $x \to \infty$ for $\sigma <k$, and so the integral cannot possibly converge. (On the other hand, if $f$ decays sufficiently fast, the Laplace transform is analytic: $e^{-x^2}$, for example, or a function with nonzero values on only a finite interval.)

Comment: But does't your proof show that $\sigma \geq \sigma_0$ is a *sufficient* condition, but not a *necessary* condition. It *could* converge even if $\sigma \le \sigma_0$ according to your proof.

Comment: Also, in the second part of the answer, you said if `$f$ grows as fast as $e^{kx}$`. How do you know such a $k$ exists so that $f$ grows at the same speed as the exponential?

Comment: I also don't see where poles come into play in your proof.

Comment: Yes, it could, but then you can pick a smaller $\sigma_0$, and keep going. The point is that either you reach a point where the Laplace transform of $|f|$ is infinite, or you don't. If you do, then either the Laplace transform of $f$ itself is finite, or it isn't. If it isn't finite, we're done. If it is, then the integral is conditionally convergent, and instead you have a region of the form $\sigma > \sigma_0$. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Region_of_convergence).

Comment: I didn't say such a $k$ did exist. I said *if* it exists, then the Laplace transform does not converge for $\sigma<k$. There are examples with no such $k$, and I provided one.

Comment: Poles don't come into the proof (as you'll have seen in the answer you accepted). But if the integral converges at a point, it is finite there, and if it's finite, it's not a pole!